# Обновление данных в ListView

Tags: android

Есть адаптер на основе BaseAdapter.

```
public class WordsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<SingleWord> words;
    int perevod;

    //Объект класса SingleWord
    SingleWord p;

    private Spinner spinner;

    //Объявляет переменную типа SlovarDBHeler
    SlovarDBHeler db;

    //Конструктор класса WordsAdapter
    WordsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleWord> words, int p, SlovarDBHeler db) {
        ctx = context;
        this.words = words;
        perevod = p;
        this.db = db;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtAlphabet;
        TextView txtWord;
        ImageButton btnFavorites;
    }

    //Сеттер для переменной perevod чтобы из MainActivity устанавливать значение переменной, а в этом адаптере брать это значение и проверять в условиях
    public void setPerevod(int perevod) {
        this.perevod = perevod;
    }

    //Геттер для переменной perevod
    public int getPerevod() {
        return perevod;
    }

    public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<SingleWord> res) {
        words = res;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setSpinner(Spinner spinner) {
        this.spinner = spinner;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinner() {
        return spinner;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return words.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return words.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Переменная типа ViewHolder
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        //Создаем объект типа SingleWord
        p = getSingleWord(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            //Создаем объект типа ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //
            viewHolder.txtAlphabet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlphabet);
            viewHolder.txtWord = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            viewHolder.btnFavorites = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Вставляем в соответствующие TextView и ImageButton данные из класса SingleWord
        viewHolder.txtWord.setText(p.word);
        viewHolder.txtAlphabet.setText(p.alphabet);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(p.bntIcon);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setFocusable(false);

        //Проверяем если значение favorites из класса SingleWord = 1, то одна иконки, иначе другая
        if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("1")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        } else if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("0")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        }

        //Событие клика на кнопку "Добавить в избранное"
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (getPerevod() == 1) {
                    System.out.println(getPerevod());
                    //Проверяем опять переменную favorites
                    if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("1")) {
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "0");

                        // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        words.get(position).setFavorites("0");
                        // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                        }
                    } else if (words.get(position).getFavorites().equals("0")){
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "1");

                        // Вставляем новый ряд в базу данных и запоминаем его идентификатор
                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarContract.SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        words.get(position).setFavorites("1");
                        // Выводим сообщение в успешном случае или при ошибке
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    SingleWord getSingleWord(int position) {
        return ((SingleWord) getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Данные выводятся в ListView из БД через этот адаптер. Пытаюсь сделать обновление данных в Listview после закрытия другого activity и возвращения в MainActivity. добавил в адаптер метод updateAdapter, а в MainActivity в onActivityResult вызываю updateAdapter но ничего не обновляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите, а зачем вам модель? Код просто ужасен

1) Наследуйтесь от `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Это позволит вам использовать `id` записи, передаваемый в `onItemClick`.

2) В вашем случае нужно **убрать модель** и код, который создаёт ваш `List` тоже. В адаптер его не надо передавать. Передавайте **только курсор**. Соответственно в `bindView` нужно получать данные прямо из БД, например, так

```
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.NAME));
```

И биндить

```
textview.setText(name);
```

3) Если вы обновляете данные в БД а потом вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged`, то перед этим следует рекверить курсор

```
cursor.requery();
```

Таким образом все у вас заработает.

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь пример где можно посмотреть как реализуется ваш вариант?

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter сам итерирует курсор (двигать позицию по курсору не надо). Вместо `getView()` в CursorAdapter используются методы `newView()` - для инфлейта и `bindView()` - для биндинга данных на айтем. [Пример](http://activity-android.blogspot.ru/2012/08/simplecursoradapter.html) кастомного адаптера

Comment: объясните новичку что такое биндинг и инфлейт? :)

Comment: @Колхозник В примере все написано. Инфлейт - создание view-объектов из xml-разметки, биндинг - связывание view-объектов с данными, которые они должны отображать.

Comment: Буду смотреть.. А пока на основе моего примера можно ли сделать то что я хочу?

Comment: @pavlofff, каша в голове из адаптеров)

Comment: @Колхозник ваш код должен обновлять данные, если при вызове `updateAdapter()` вы передаете аргументом изменненый `ArrayList` (с другими данными)

Comment: ок, спасибо. Думаю разберусь. Нужно как-нибудь переписать приложение используя simplecursoradapter, а то у меня гавнокод получился через коллекции все сделано

Comment: Ну да :) сами подумайте вы берете данные из БД, форммруете коллекцию, потом передаете её в адаптер, там парсите )))) `SimpleCursorAdapter` для этого нужен, читайте, удачи. Если мой ответ вам помог отметьте его правильным (галочка слева)